# Issues launching Python Interactive in VS Code

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, conda

I am trying to setup Visual Studio Code using Python Extension and Anaconda. My current environment is set to {'base':conda}. However, I keep getting the error given below:

> Command failed: C:/Anaconda/Scripts/activate && conda activate base &&
>   echo 'e8b39361-0157-4923-80e1-22d70d46dee6' && python "c:/Users/Varun
>   Srivastava/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.2.63072/pythonFiles/printEnvVariables.py"
>   Access is denied. Access is denied. The system cannot find the file
>   Srivastava\AppData\Local\Temp\conda-10598-3029.tmp. Could Not Find
>   C:\Users\Varun Srivastava\AppData\Local\Temp\conda-10598-3029.tmp
>   '"C:\Users\Varun"' is not recognized as an internal or external
>   command, operable program or batch file. Access is denied. 'conda' is
>   not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or
>   batch file.

As far as I could gauge, there is an issue finding some .conda .tmp files, and this could be because there is a space in the directory name "C:\Users\Varun Srivastava\AppData\Local\Temp\conda-10598-3029.tmp" .

Any suggestions?

Specs:
Python 3.7.4 via Anaconda
VS Code 1.42.1

Comment: Where do get this error message? Right in the terminal in VS Code or in some logfile?